# Generate a matrix containing all possible numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, combinations

I am trying to achieve multiple matrices that will cover the full set of numbers. For example say I want to generate 5 matrices of length 10 that cover all the numbers from 1-20.

So matrix one will contain half the numbers say

```
m1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

while matrix two contains

```
m2 = [11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20];
```

Although this satisfies my condition with only two matrices not 5, I preferably need to generate all matrices randomly. Other than randomly generating the matrices and checking all values are generated is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
>> l=[1:20,randi(20,1,30)];
>> vec=l(randperm(length(l)));
>> v=reshape(vec,5,10);
```

The first line generates an array of 50 numbers from 1 to 20. It guarantees that each such number appears at least once. The second line randomizes the order of the numbers. The third line reshapes the vector into an array of arrays (that is, a 2D matrix, where each row is one of the arrays).

Comment: Ah nice, this is very close to what I am trying to achieve. The only difference is I would like to allow for repeat entries.. sorry for the confusion. Im just trying to think how i can apply the randperm/reshape somehow

Comment: So you basically want to create 5 vectors of length 10, each one of them have entries restricted to 1-20?

Comment: Yes so each one contains the possible entries 1-20, but there must at least be one occurrence of the 1-20

Comment: So I can do randi(20,5,10) although this doesn't guarantee that I have every number 0(from 1to 20) in the output